# Update URLSession after new data is created inside database

Tags: swift, neo4j, graphql, apollo

### I am using the following:

- Apollo iOS
- Neo4j Database (with the GraphQL plugin)
- GraphQL

---

### Singleton Class for Connection

My code below is to connect to the GraphQL endpoint which happens to be my Neo4j Database.

```
class Network {
    static let shared = Network()
    private(set) lazy var apollo: ApolloClient = {

        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:7474/graphql/")!
        let keychain = KeychainSwift()
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral

        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "\(String(describing: keychain.get("neo.auth")))"]

        return ApolloClient(
            networkTransport: HTTPNetworkTransport(url: url, session: URLSession(configuration: configuration))
        )
    }()
}
```

---

When I create data inside my database via my app this works great however if I then query to the database to return all the data, the newly created data is not found. The data is in the database because I can see it in the browser and also if I restart my app and then run the exact same code to return all the data; it returns it.

The other thing I have tried to do is run two instances of my app side by side in the simulator. Both apps have the same features and can import/export data. When I create new data via one instance the data is created in the database successfully however upon importing the data in the other instance of the app - it returns nothing (Both apps being ran at the same time).

### My Import Code

```
    func importData(){
    let apollo = Network.shared.apollo
    //Import all data from the graph database
    apollo.fetch(query: GetAllQuery()) { result in
    guard let data = try? result.get().data else { return }
        print(data.jsonObject.values)
    }
}
```

The only thing I can think of is that the session is not updating when new data is created in the database. The reason I feel this is because if I relaunch the app and run my import function it actually returns all the new data. I need the connection to update when new data is created, is there a way I can refresh the connection upon data creation?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix that is working so far for me:

```
apollo.clearCache()
```

I am using this before I run a query to the database and so far it has pulled down all the correct data. My issue was that when I exported data to the database and then tried importing it (or reading it) directly after it never returned anything or returned data that already existed in the system.